# calling javascript function with parameters in href

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

I am working on a pagination project. I need to create a pagination function, which will pass the page number and execute the getData(page) function to get page data and display. However, I got undefined with my page number.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var firstPage = "${firstPage}";
  var lastPage = "${lastPage}";
  var currentPage = "${currentPage}";
  var totalPage = "${totalPage}";
  setPagination(firstPage, lastPage, currentPage, totalPage);
});

function setPagination(firstPage, lastPage, currentPage, totalPage) {
  var paginationHTML = "";
  if (currentPage != 1) {
    paginationHTML = paginationHTML + '<a href="#" onclick="getData(1);>|&lt;</a>';
    paginationHTML = paginationHTML + '<a href="#" onclick="getData(parseInt(currentPage)-1);>&lt;</a>';
  }
  for (var i = parseInt(firstPage); i <= parseInt(lastPage); i++) {
    if (i == currentPage) {
      paginationHTML = paginationHTML + '<a href="#" onclick="getData(i); class="active">' + i + '</a>';
    } else {
      paginationHTML = paginationHTML + '<a href="#" onclick="getData(i);>' + i + '</a>';
    }
  }
  if (currentPage != lastPage) {
    paginationHTML = paginationHTML + '<a href="#" onclick="getData(parseInt(currentPage)+1);>&gt;</a>';
    paginationHTML = paginationHTML + '<a href="#" onclick="getData(totalPage);>&gt;|</a>';
  }

  $(".pagination").append(paginationHTML);
}
```

Comment: What are you getting by this `var firstPage= "${firstPage}";`?

Comment: _"I got undefined with my page number."_ What line exactly?

Comment: firstPage is getting from controller. I checked firstPage is fine, it can show the number

Comment: I write console.log(page); in getData(page). I got undefined

Comment: Variables in `onclick` are evaluated in the global scope, you can't reference local variables.

Comment: I have no idea how to make this work @Barmar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables in `onclick` attributes are evaluated in the global scope, so you can't reference local variables there.

You can instead expand the variables when creating the HTML strings. Template literals make this easier.

You were also missing the ending `"` for all your `onclick` attributes.

```
function setPagination(firstPage, lastPage, currentPage, totalPage) {
  var paginationHTML = "";
  if (currentPage != 1) {
    paginationHTML = paginationHTML + '<a href="#" onclick="getData(1);">|&lt;</a>';
    paginationHTML = paginationHTML + `<a href="#" onclick="getData(${currentPage}-1);">&lt;</a>`;
  }
  for (var i = parseInt(firstPage); i <= parseInt(lastPage); i++) {
    if (i == currentPage) {
      paginationHTML += `<a href="#" onclick="getData(${i});" class="active">${i}</a>`;
    } else {
      paginationHTML += `<a href="#" onclick="getData(${i});">${i}</a>`;
    }
  }
  if (currentPage != lastPage) {
    paginationHTML += `<a href="#" onclick="getData(${currentPage}+1);">&gt;</a>`;
    paginationHTML += `<a href="#" onclick="getData(${totalPage});">&gt;|</a>`;
  }

  $(".pagination").append(paginationHTML);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass `i` like `getData(i)` as a string. You have to send the actual `i` in the parameter when you're dynamically calling the function from string.

Instead of

```
paginationHTML = paginationHTML + '<a href="#" onclick="getData(i); class="active">' + i + '</a>';
```

Write

```
  paginationHTML = paginationHTML + '<a href="#" onclick="getData('+i+'); class="active">' + i + '</a>';
```

Change in other places as well so that you can get the value of `i` in `getData(i)`